# Best way to parse a file with links exported from Delicious.com using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, delicious-api

I want to parse an html file containing links exported from Delicious. I am using Nokogiri for the parsing. The file has the following structure:

```
<DT>
   <A HREF="http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2009/01/27/sprite_optim/"
      ADD_DATE="1233132422"
      PRIVATE="0"
      TAGS="irw_20">mezzoblue § Sprite Optimization</A>
<DT>
   <A HREF="http://datamining.typepad.com/data_mining/2008/11/minority-report-interface.html" 
      ADD_DATE="1226827542" 
      PRIVATE="0" 
      TAGS="irw_20">Minority Report Interface</A>
<DT>
   <A HREF="http://www.windowshop.com/" 
      ADD_DATE="1225267658" 
      PRIVATE="0" 
      TAGS="irw_20">Amazon Windowshop Beta</A>
<DD>Window shopping from Amazon
```

As you can see the link information is in the DT-tag and some links have a comment in a DD-tag.

I do the following to get the link information:

```
doc.xpath('//dt//a').each do |node|
  title = node.text
  url = node['href']
  tags = node['tags']
  puts "#{title}, #{url}, #{tags}"
end
```

My question is how do I get the link information AND the comment when a dd tag is present?

Comment: You want to get the text for the `<a>` tags followed by `<DD>` tags? Please give a sample of the desired output.

Comment: It might be more convenient to export the data using: `curl -o output.xml --user yourusername https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/all` and parse the xml-file.

Comment: Or use typhoeus to retrieve it and pass the body directly to Nokogiri.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted elements. :)

Comment: If you can, try to use delicious data through API, it should be simpler than scrapping HTML. There are ruby tools for that. https://github.com/weppos/www-delicious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how do I get the link
>   information AND the comment when a dd
>   tag is present?

**Use**:

```
//DT/a | //DT[a]/following-sibling::*[1][self::DD]
```

This selects all `a` elements that have a `DT` parent and all `DD` elements that are the immediate following sibling element of a `DT` element that has an `a` child.

**Note**: The use of the `//` is strongly discouraged because it usually leads to inefficiencies and anomalies in its use for the developers.

**Whenever the structure of the XML document is known, avoid using the `//` abbreviation**.

Comment: Sweet! I had to make DT's and the DD's lowercase, then it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear about what you are looking for.

First, the HTML is malformed because the `<DT>` tags are not closed correctly, and there is an illegal character in the first `a` tag's text that Ruby 1.9.2 doesn't like because it's not UTF-8. I converted the character to an entity in TextMate.

```
html = %{
<DT>
  <A HREF="http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2009/01/27/sprite_optim/" ADD_DATE="1233132422" PRIVATE="0" TAGS="irw_20">mezzoblue &sect; Sprite Optimization</A>
<DT>
  <A HREF="http://datamining.typepad.com/data_mining/2008/11/minority-report-interface.html" ADD_DATE="1226827542" PRIVATE="0" TAGS="irw_20">Minority Report Interface</A>
<DT>
  <A HREF="http://www.windowshop.com/" ADD_DATE="1225267658" PRIVATE="0" TAGS="irw_20">Amazon Windowshop Beta</A>
<DD>Window shopping from Amazon
}
```

That HTML parses to this in Nokogiri after it tries to fix it up:

```
(rdb:1) print doc.to_html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<dt>
  <a href="http://mezzoblue.com/archives/2009/01/27/sprite_optim/" add_date="1233132422" private="0" tags="irw_20">mezzoblue § Sprite Optimization</a>
<dt>
  <a href="http://datamining.typepad.com/data_mining/2008/11/minority-report-interface.html" add_date="1226827542" private="0" tags="irw_20">Minority Report Interface</a>
<dt>
  <a href="http://www.windowshop.com/" add_date="1225267658" private="0" tags="irw_20">Amazon Windowshop Beta</a>
</dt>
</dt>
</dt>
<dd>Window shopping from Amazon
</dd>
</body></html>
```

Notice how the closing `dt` tags are grouped just before the only `dd` tag? That's icky, but ok because it doesn't change how we have to look for the `dd` content.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html, nil, 'UTF-8')

comments = []
doc.css('dt + dd').each do |a|
  comments << a.text
end
puts comments

# >> Window shopping from Amazon
```

That means, find `<dt>` followed by `<dd>`. You don't/can't look for `dt` followed by `a` followed by `dd` because that's not how the HTML parses. It would really be `dt` followed by `dd`, which is what "`dt + dd`" means.

The other way it seemed like your question could read was that you were looking for the content of the `a` tags:

```
comments = []
doc.css('a').each do |a|
  comments << a.text
end
puts comments

# >> mezzoblue § Sprite Optimization
# >> Minority Report Interface
# >> Amazon Windowshop Beta
```

Comment: I have clarified my question. I would like the output to be the content of the a-tag directly followed by the content of the dd-tag when the dd-tag is present.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the:

```
<DD>Window shopping from Amazon
```

has an ending /DD tag, I can't tell from just your snippet of the page. If so, you could do:

```
comment = node.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling.text rescue nil
```

You need to call next_sibling twice because the first one will match a \n (new line) or whitespace. You could remove all the new lines prior to parsing the page to avoid the double call. That might also be a good idea in case there's more than 1 new line character after the DT tag

Comment: I just realized the DT tags aren't closed, I just assumed it was at the end of the line and I didn't scroll. In that case, next_sibling might not work as expected.